# unable to get debug signature key for my android application

Tags: android

I am new to android. I got one issue during run my first hello world application in android.The error is like:

```
Error generating final archive: Unable to get debug signature key
```

I see my default path of debug keystore  Windows->Preference->Android->Build. The path is

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_17\.android\debug.keystore
```

But there is not creating any .android file. 
Please help me how to solve the above issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quit Eclipse, then delete the .android directory.  Then, re-run AVD manager and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

The default storage location for debug.keystore is in ~/.android/ on OS X and Linux, in C:\Documents and Settings\.android\ on Windows XP, and in C:\Users\.android\ on Windows Vista and Windows 7. [REFRENCE](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: but for my case its not creating the .android

Comment: change the default path of debug keystore in Windows->Preference->Android->Build with as per suggested OS.